# Qt 5.5: module "QtAudioEngine" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I'm running the official Qt 5.5 SDK on Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to play 3D sounds in QML:

```
import QtAudioEngine 1.0
```

The project file:

```
qt += multimedia
```

The import statement results in `qrc:///Main.qml:1:1: module "QtAudioEngine" is not installed`. I'm a bit confused as I can see that the needed libs are in the SDK. What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the official Qt SDK : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51567

Comment: @SAt you have to recompile Qt yourself with openal-soft available somewhere in the include path

Comment: I installed QT 15.5.2 with installer in win10! without compile to setup it.